# Reducing a expression to find a distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

This question is related to my privious question [Find $P(X=x|Y=y)$ while giving P(X), P(Y) and $P(Y=y|X=x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318041/find-px-xy-y-while-giving-px-py-and-py-yx-x)
If I do the math I get:
$$P(X=x|Y=y) =\frac{P(Y=y|X=x)P(X=x) }{P(Y=y)} =\frac{\binom{n}{y} x^y(1-x)^{n-y}\cdot 1}{\frac{1}{n+1}}=\binom{n}{y} x^y(1-x)^{n-y}(n+1)$$
But I can't see how to multiply this smart so I get a distribution. Can anyone help me with that? Is there a trick?

Comment: what do you mean by "how to multiply this smart so I get a distribution"? can you elaborate?

Comment: Is the found result just the solution or can I reduce it so it has a form of a known distribution with some parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \binom{n}{y}x^y(1-x)^{n-y}(n+1) \, dx\\
&=(n+1) \binom{n}{y}\int_0^1x^y(1-x)^{n-y}\, dx \\
&= 1
\end{align}

It is a valid distribution.

\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma(1+y)\Gamma(n+1-y)}{\Gamma(1+y+n+1-y)} &=\frac{y!(n-y)!}{(n+1)!}
\end{align}

Notice that we have \begin{align}\binom{n}{y}x^y(1-x)^{n-y}(n+1) &=(n+1) \binom{n}{y}x^{1+y-1}(1-x)^{n+1-y-1} \\
&=\frac{x^{1+y-1}(1-x)^{n+1-y-1}}{\frac1{n+1\binom{n}{y}}}\\
&=\frac{x^{1+y-1}(1-x)^{n+1-y-1}}{B(1+y, n+1-y)}\end{align}

The distribition is [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), Beta($1+y, n+1-y$).